# How do I make a .mouseleave() function trigger one time

Tags: jquery

I'm creating an exit pop-up that should trigger once. After the user closes the pop-up it reappears when they `.mouseleave()` again. This is my function:

```
    $('body').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#popup-container').css('display', 'grid');
        $('#popup-bg').fadeIn();
        Cookies.set('~plan-popup', true, {expires: 7, path: ''});
    });
```

Every post I've found explains how to use `.one()` with `.one("click", function()`. I want to use `.one()` with `.mouseleave()` so those posts do not help. (I realize the titles look similar, but before you mark as a duplicate please go read those other posts, they do not answer my question.)

Even the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for `.one()` doesn't help much with this.

How can I make this `.mouseleave()` function trigger only once?

**Correction**: I need to familiarize myself with jQuery terminology. I didn't realize that `.mouseleave()` is an "event". The documentation does actually go over this here:

> `.one( events [, data ], handler )`
> **Events**
>   Type: String
>   A string containing one or more JavaScript event types, such as "click" or "submit," or custom event names.

Comment: Otherwise, `$('body').mouseleave(function () {` -->  `$('body').one('mouseleave', function () {`.  The documentation is pretty clear

Comment: The popup only triggers when you leave the body, as intended. It's an exit-intent popup. Where do you see this in the documentation? Do you have a link?

Comment: Nvm, it's mouseout that bubbles.  So yeah, using `one()` as the api specifies will allow the binding to happen at most once.

Comment: Thank you. I'm almost certain I tried `.one('mouseleave', function()` before and it didn't work, but it is working now. If you answer the post I'll accept it.

Comment: @Taplar btw you were right about the documentation. I didn't realize `.mouseleave()` was an "event". I've updated my post for clarity.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much any time you are dealing with a method that creates an event listener, it's going to use `on()` under the hood.  Which is why some developers encourage the use of `on()` vs the wrapper methods, for clarity.  And not only that, but if you use `on()`, you're just one step away from using the delegate version of it, or switching to `one` if need be.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look a little more into `.on()` thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseleave()` in jQuery is simply a wrapper around `on('mouseleave', ...)`.  So to use the `one()` version which will automatically remove it after the first execution, you just need to use the non-wrapper binding with one.

```
$(selector).one('mouseleave', ...)
```